# Merge thousand of IMERG 30-min rainfall netcdf files into single netcdf

Tags: nco, cdo-climate

I have 8736 nc4 files (30-minute rainfall from 1 Jun - 31 Dec 2000) downloaded from https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GPM_3IMERGHH_06/summary?keywords=IMERG with naming convention

`3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20000601-S000000-E002959.0000.V06B.HDF5.nc4`

`3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20000601-S003000-E005959.0030.V06B.HDF5.nc4`

Start Date/Time: All files in GPM will be named using the start date/time of the temporal period of the data contained in the product. The field has two subfields separated by a hyphen.

Start Date: `YYYYMMDD`
Start Time: Begin with Capital `S` and follow with `HHMMSS`
End Time: Begin with Capital `E` and follow with `HHMMSS`
Hours are presented in a 24-hour time format, with ‘00’ indicating midnight. All times in GPM will be in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

The half-hour sequence starts at `0000`, and increments by 30 for each half hour of the day.

I would like to merge all the files into single nc4. The reason is, I would like to do further processing ie. calculate rolling sum to get 6 or 12hour rainfall accumulation, and other analysis.

I followed suggestion from other similar topic by using:
`cdo mergetime file*.nc4 output.nc4` and `ncecat file*.nc4 output.nc4`
But both are failed with error `argument list too long`

As suggested from below answer to split the files into separate lists (by months), I did using following script: `for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 12); do mkdir -p "Month$i"; mv 3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.????$i*.nc4 "Month$i"; done`

And increase the limit, now `ulimit -s` on my mac give answer `65536`

Then I tried again using `ncecat file*.nc4 output.nc4` in a folder with 1440 files and its worked.

But I just realized that the result has record dimension UNLIMITED and time = 1.

[image: ncdump]

When I open the output.nc4 using Panoply, Record = 1440 and Time only have 1 information: Date 1 Jun 2000

[image: Panoply]

This is something new for me as new user, I am expecting I will have similar output like I did when using Daily or Monthly data, the time dimension will have UNLIMITED value.

Any suggestion how to solve above problem? Is there any step that I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a shell limitation (possibly Windows?) to me. `ncecat` keeps at most 3 files open at one time. The [NCO Users Guide](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#input_files) describes multiple workarounds for handling arbitrarily long lists of input files. At least one of these methods will work for you. HINT: Try the `-n` option combined with symbolic links as shown in the manual.

Edit in response to comment, 2020-10-22:
Here is how the manual demonstrates creating nicely named symbolic links to a million files:

```
# Create enumerated symbolic links
/bin/ls | grep \.nc | perl -e \
'$idx=1;while(<STDIN>){chop;symlink $_,sprintf("%06d.nc",$idx++);}'
ncecat -n 999999,6,1 000001.nc foo.nc
# Remove symbolic links when finished
/bin/rm ??????.nc
```

You can shorten the number of arguments piped to /bin/ls by constraining the list with a pattern, so the shell stops complaining, then repeat until all your files have a link. Then you execute the single `ncecat` command shown in the example, with *one* filename, and you are done.

Edit in response to newest question, 20201101:

It seems like you used `ncecat` when what you really need is `ncrcat`. Their difference is a bit subtle. Now that you solved the shell limit, the easiest way to solve the issue is just to re-do the command with `ncrcat` instead of `ncecat`:

```
ncrcat file*.nc4 output.nc4
```

Comment: I couldn't open above link (strange), but I assume it same with this http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Large-Numbers-of-Files and I have tried using option ```-n loop``` and also following example on the link using ```ls | grep```. But again experience the same error, argument list too long, for ncecat and grep

Comment: Thanks for example script, but as new user and I have limited knowledge to understand the script, its difficult for me to understand and implement your code. I have updated my question and using ```ncecat``` I am able to merge all but with less amount of nc4 files. But unfortunately the result is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a stack limit on the argument size passed to the command, you can see this by typing

```
ulimit -s
```

and you will probably get an answer of 8192.

You can try increasing this, e.g.

```
ulimit -s 32768
```

and see if that resolves the problem.  On my MAC I could not go above this new value; attempting to set this soft limit to 65536, gave me a "*ulimit: value exceeds hard limit*" error.

Comment: I have revise the question and increase the limit, got 65536. But still confuse with the result.

Answer (score -1):

This is almost certainly an OS specific problem. If you are on Linux, you can only have 1024 files open at once, by default. I do not know about macOS.

You could change the limit (e.g. see [here](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/)), but that is probably not a good idea.

So the best thing would be to split the files into 9 separate lists, create 9 files with those merged, and then merge those files.

Comment: I am using macOS. I followed the link, and increase the limit but still experience the same issue. Anyway I will try to create separate list later if I couldn't find any better idea, because I will do similar approach to merge data from 2000.

Comment: I follow your suggestion to split the files into separate list (by months wit less amount of files), and able to merge but the result is not as expected. I have modified the question to make it clearer with information on file that I am dealing.